# Need to find consecutive sequence like "6789" or "abcd" in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, search

I need help to find consecutive sequence for example more than 3 characters in ascending order. I've already implemented one solution but It's not universal.
Examples what should be found - "1234", "abcd", "5678".
And what shouldn't be found - "123", "adced", "123abc", "89:;"
**Particularly the case "89:;"**, symbol ":" - is 58 in uniCode and "9" - is 57, that's why my approach does not work in the case.
Implementation should be in swift.

**Additional clarification**

For now it would be enough to find the sequences only in English letters and numbers.

```
private func findSequence(sequenceLength: Int, in string: String) -> Bool {

    let scalars = string.unicodeScalars
    var unicodeArray: [Int] = scalars.map({ Int($0.value) })

    var currentLength: Int = 1
    var i = 0
    for number in unicodeArray {
        if i+1 >= unicodeArray.count {
            break
        }
        let nextNumber = unicodeArray[i+1]

        if number+1 == nextNumber {
            currentLength += 1
        } else {
            currentLength = 1
        }
        if currentLength >= sequenceLength {
            return true
        }
        i += 1
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: What makes "89:;" different from "1234"? Both are consecutive Unicode characters – why should the latter be found but not the former? What about "αβγδ" or "#$%&"?

Comment: I check password for the sequence, and for users it's not logical that they cannot used the case "89:;"

Comment: *You* have to describe the exact requirement, otherwise we can only guess what you need. Perhaps you are thinking of consecutive digits and letters – but what about greek or german letters (äöüß) or persian or hebrew digits?

Comment: @MartinR For now it would be enough to find the sequences only in English letters and numbers.

Comment: Is that `unicodeArray` or `uniCodeArray`? Are those the same variable?

Comment: @user28434 Yes, are the same, it is my misspelling.

Comment: Your code works, just add a check to make sure `number` is a letter or digit first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check for sequence with `CharacterSet`

```
func findSequence(sequenceLength: Int, in string: String) -> Bool {
    // It would be better to extract this out of func
    let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let lowercase = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "a"..."z")
    let uppercase = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."Z")
    let controlSet = digits.union(lowercase).union(uppercase)
    // ---

    let scalars = string.unicodeScalars
    let unicodeArray = scalars.map({ $0 })

    var currentLength: Int = 1
    var i = 0
    for number in unicodeArray where controlSet.contains(number) {
        if i+1 >= unicodeArray.count {
            break
        }
        let nextNumber = unicodeArray[i+1]

        if UnicodeScalar(number.value+1) == nextNumber {
            currentLength += 1
        } else {
            currentLength = 1
        }
        if currentLength >= sequenceLength {
            return true
        }
        i += 1
    }
    return false
}
```

---

I did assumed that `"a" ... "z"` and `"A"..."Z"` are consecutive here, to make it in range, but it may be better do explicitly list all the symbols you want.

Or use [`CharacterSet.alphanumerics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779632-alphanumerics), but is not limited to basic latin alphabet.

Comment: This did not consider "4321" as invalid. How to detect this?

Comment: @USER9561, ah, it looks like I forgot about digits in 2018. There should be `union` with [`CharacterSet.decimalDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779641-decimaldigits) too

Answer (score 0):

```
    var  data = [1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,6,5,4,5,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,1,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,11,2,5,4,56,6,7,9,8,1,2,3]
    
    for i in 0...data.count{
        if i+2 < data.count{
            if Int(data[i] + data[i+2]) / 2 == data[i+1] && Int(data[i] + data[i+2]) % data[i+1] == 0 && data[i+1] != 1 && data[i] < data[i+1]{
                print(data[i] ,data[i+1], data[i+2])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what your code is exactly doing.

Comment: this is a solution for finding sequence in ascending from an array of integers in swift(iOS)...